# How can I relay the data from component 1 to component 3 with the same service?

Tags: angular

My codes are posted to the [URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdymxt).

I have a TransferObjService object, an "aa" component and a "bb" component.

I use TransferObjService object to transfer the string "Angular" to component aa.

In component aa, I add "aa" before the string "Angular" and then use the same TransferObjService object to transfer the resultant string to component "bb".

In the component "bb", it should display the word "aa Angular", however, it shows "Angular" only.

How can I make it works?

Comment: can you share the code for the components and service?

Comment: @tayyab_fareed I have edited the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a `BehaviorSubject`, otherwise the first value of the stream is never emitted.

Also, consider using `take(1)` in your AA component, to avoid infinite loops.

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkxruh?file=src/app/aa/aa.component.ts)**

```
export class TransferObjService {
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject('');
  constructor() { }

  sendObj(obj) {
    this.subject.next(obj);
  }

  accessObj() {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

}
```